# Selenium Node is disconnecting with grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am facing challenges with Node machine is getting disconnected with Hub. Because of this, my daily batch schedules in Jenkins are failing. The Hub and Node were connected for a day or 2 days, but later they are getting disconnected.

Can someone help me why they are disconnecting.

Following is my node configuration(node.json):

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 17946,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://jenkins.abc.edu:4444",
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Comment: Update the question with _Hub_ and _Node_ startup commands and logs along with the error stack trace including the binary version info

Comment: The node and hub are connected for a day or 2 days, afterwards node is getting disconnected with hub. We are not touching this Node VM, but somehow it is getting disconnected. Because of this, our daily batch schedule in Jenkins are failing. So can someone tell me how i can make sure the Node and Hub are stay connected long?

Comment: Can someone help on this query?